# Firebase Deploy error - There was an unknown problem while trying to parse function triggers. Please ensure you are using Node.js v6 or greater

Tags: firebase

I'm getting `There was an unknown problem while trying to parse function triggers. Please ensure you are using Node.js v6 or greater`

when trying to do `firebase deploy --only functions`

I tried with `node -v v10.10.0` `node -v v8.11.1` `node -v v10.15.3`

Background: this is a project that I develop 6 month ago, it worked with no issue, but today I tried to re-deploy (no changes in the code) and I get this error.

I have no idea how to work from here, would appreciate any idea.

here is the full log:

```js
firebase deploy --only functions

=== Deploying to 'invoice-manager-251609'...

i  deploying functions
Running command: npm --prefix "$RESOURCE_DIR" run lint

> functions@ lint D:\work\ocr\receiptWeb\functions
> eslint .


D:\work\ocr\receiptWeb\functions\index.js
  127:25  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting
  127:25  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting
  128:35  warning  Don't make functions within a loop  no-loop-func
  132:40  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting
  132:40  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting
  134:44  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting
  146:38  warning  Don't make functions within a loop  no-loop-func
  424:28  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting
  424:28  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting
  465:28  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting
  465:28  warning  Avoid nesting promises              promise/no-nesting

D:\work\ocr\receiptWeb\functions\ReceiptGv.js
  368:43  warning  Don't make functions within a loop  no-loop-func

✖ 12 problems (0 errors, 12 warnings)

+  functions: Finished running predeploy script.
i  functions: ensuring necessary APIs are enabled...
+  functions: all necessary APIs are enabled
i  functions: preparing functions directory for uploading...

Error: There was an unknown problem while trying to parse function triggers. Please ensure you are using Node.js v6 or greater.
```

NOTE: the warnings are not new, and I could deploy the project with them in the past.

sometimes it gives this addiation line `Having trouble? Try again or contact support with contents of firebase-debug.log`

but I couldn't find any info about `firebase-debug.log` in google.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Solve by installing node v8.17.0

Comment: Solved on Win7 by uninstalling a v16 version of Node.js in control panel programs and downloading and installing v13.14.0 msi from https://nodejs.org/download/release/v13.14.0/

Answer (score 7):

Installing a different node verion didn't work for me, but removing the `node-modules` folder from functions and then re-installing dependencies did.

Comment: This worked for me, may be because i had to switch to node v10 since v8 is deprecated now, and `node_modules` was previously installed with v8

Answer (score 0):

Please check your Node version by typing ( node -v ) in your console or Terminal and also check your Package.json which is inside functions and check the below code.

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "14"
  },
```

The above means I want to deploy firebase. In this case, I should already install node 14 or 14 + version on my pc.

Answer (score 0):

There was a bug in firebase-tools (I can't remember what version now) which was fixed. Just make sure you have the latest running:

```
npm install -g firebase-tools@latest
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to update Node versions or dependencies
we often run the command:

```
firebase deploy --only functions
```

use these simple steps:

1: Go to the package.json file

in the script object add the following:

```
"deploy": "firebase deploy --only \"functions:<your function name>\"",
```

it will look like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "lint": "eslint .",
    "serve": "firebase serve",
    "shell": "firebase functions:shell",
    "start": "npm run shell",
    "deploy": "firebase deploy --only \"functions:app\"",
    "logs": "firebase functions:log"
  },
```

2: then run this **deploy** script from package.json file.

it will work!.

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are running the app in the same port that is going to be deployed.
In my case a just had to stop running the script locally and it worked with no problem